# Pygame Code screen keeps opening with game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My team and I implemented a game in Python using Pygame. Whenever the game is run, alongside the GUI there is an extra black window that opens alongside, a .exe window. Is there anyway to stop it from opening?

Answer (score 0):

That is a command window, specifically one running `python[Version Number].exe`. To remove it simply change the scripts file extension to `.pyw` instead of `.py`, which changes the file type to the same thing [Python], but without the console window opening too.

So for example, `script.py` would become `script.pyw`

Comment: I tried that but it forces the GUI window to shut as well